# Copied project error Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, project, callstack

I copied a whole project one file at a time and changed the files to fit to the new project as the errors piled up. All the errors rectified but now it says project item unavailable. I never seen this error before.

Here is the error:
[image]

I exchanged a settings file and now there is a new error:

[image]

Comment: Well it is to do with a form I think

Comment: Try restarting visual studio if you havent already.  Sometimes that does the trick magically.

Comment: Digitalfront, write your comment as an answer, so the OP can mark this question as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a comment:
Try restarting visual studio if you havent already. Sometimes that does the trick magically.